# Weights&Biases Sweep Keras K-Fold Validation

Tags: python, keras, k-fold, wandb

I'm using Weights&Biases Cloud-based sweeps with Keras.
So first i create a new Sweep within a W&B Project with a config like following:

```yaml
description: LSTM Model
method: random
metric:
  goal: maximize
  name: val_accuracy
name: LSTM-Sweep
parameters:
  batch_size:
    distribution: int_uniform
    max: 128
    min: 32
  epochs:
    distribution: constant
    value: 200
  node_size1:
    distribution: categorical
    values:
    - 64
    - 128
    - 256
  node_size2:
    distribution: categorical
    values:
    - 64
    - 128
    - 256
  node_size3:
    distribution: categorical
    values:
    - 64
    - 128
    - 256
  node_size4:
    distribution: categorical
    values:
    - 64
    - 128
    - 256
  node_size5:
    distribution: categorical
    values:
    - 64
    - 128
    - 256
  num_layers:
    distribution: categorical
    values:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
  optimizer:
    distribution: categorical
    values:
    - Adam
    - Adamax
    - Adagrad
  path:
    distribution: constant
    value: "./path/to/data/"
program: sweep.py
project: SLR
```

My `sweep.py` file looks something like this:

```py
# imports
init = wandb.init(project="my-project", reinit=True)
config = wandb.config

def main():
    skfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, 
    shuffle=True, random_state=7)
    cvscores = []
    group_id = wandb.util.generate_id()
    X,y = # load data
    i = 0
    for train, test in skfold.split(X,y):
        i=i+1
        run = wandb.init(group=group_id, reinit=True, name=group_id+"#"+str(i))
        model = # build model
        model.fit([...], WandBCallback())
        cvscores.append([...])
        wandb.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Starting this with the `wandb agent` command within the folder of `sweep.py`.

What i experienced with this setup is, that with the first wandb.init() call a new run is initialized. Okay, i could just remove that. But when calling wandb.init() for the second time it seems to lose track of the sweep it is running in. Online an empty run is listed in the sweep (because of the first wandb.init() call), all other runs are listed inside the project, but not in the sweep.

My goal is to have a run for each fold of the k-Fold cross-validation. At least i thought this would be the right way of doing this.
Is there a different approach to combine sweeps with keras k-fold cross validation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We put together an example of how to accomplish k-fold cross validation:

https://github.com/wandb/examples/tree/master/examples/wandb-sweeps/sweeps-cross-validation

The solution requires some contortions for the wandb library to spawn multiple jobs on behalf of a launched sweep job.

The basic idea is:

- The agent requests a new set of parameters from the cloud hosted parameter server.  This is the run called `sweep_run` in the main function.
- Send information about what the folds should process over a multiprocessing queue to waiting processes
- Each spawned process logs to their own run, organized with group and job_type to enable auto-grouping in the UI
- When the process is finished, it sends the primary metric over a queue to the parent sweep run
- The sweep run reads metrics from the child runs and logs it to the sweep run so that the sweep can use that result to impact future parameter choices and/or hyperband early termination optimizations

Example visualizations of the sweep and k-fold grouping can be seen here:

- Sweep: https://app.wandb.ai/jeffr/examples-sweeps-cross-validation/sweeps/vp0fsvku
- K-fold Grouping: https://app.wandb.ai/jeffr/examples-sweeps-cross-validation/groups/vp0fsvku

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Even though you should usually include the code in your answers, in this case it gets quite verbose, so you do link it, but still make the effort of explaining the solution inside the answer. This is exactly what should be done in this cases. Thanks for your answer, you're getting my upvote.