# How to use StratifiedKFold with wandb sweeps?

Tags: python, cross-validation, k-fold, wandb

I have the following piece of code - it is a train function for Logistic regression. I run sweeps to be able to compare hyperparameter tuning results. My issue is that I don't know how to incorporate StratifiedKFold to work with sweeps. I would appreciate it if someone can help me modify my code:

```
def train(
    confing=None,
    X_train = features_train,
    y_train = labels_train,
    X_test = features_test,
    y_test = labels_test
):
    with wandb.init(
        project=WANDB_PROJECT_NAME, 
        entity="name", 
        config=config_defaults,
        tags=['logistic regression', 'tf-idf', 'l2', 'class weight', 'C'],
        notes='Logistic regression run with several regularizations and with either None penalty or l2 penalty, and ''balanced'' or pre-calculated class_weight.'
    ):
        config = wandb.config
        
        log_reg = LogisticRegression(
            penalty=config.penalty,
            C = config.C,
            class_weight = config.class_weight
        )
        
        log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
        
        y_pred = log_reg.predict(X_test)
        y_proba = log_reg.predict_proba(X_test)
        labels=list(map(str,y_labels['label'].unique()))
        
        # Visualize single plot
        cm = wandb.sklearn.plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels)
        
        score_f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
        
        sm = wandb.sklearn.plot_summary_metrics(
        log_reg, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
        
        roc = wandb.sklearn.plot_roc(y_test, y_proba)
        
        wandb.log({
            "f1-weighted-log-regr-1": score_f1, 
            "roc-log-regr-1": roc, 
            "conf-mat-log-regr-1": cm,
            "summary-metrics-log-regr-1": sm
            })

sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep_config, project="log-regr")
wandb.agent(sweep_id, function=train)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should solve your issue.
For getting multiple metrics, you can consider 'cross_validate' function instead of 'cross_val_score' function.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


def train(
    confing=None,
    X_train = features_train,
    y_train = labels_train,
    X_test = features_test,
    y_test = labels_test
):
    with wandb.init(
        project=WANDB_PROJECT_NAME, 
        entity="name", 
        config=config_defaults,
        tags=['logistic regression', 'tf-idf', 'l2', 'class weight', 'C'],
        notes='Logistic regression run with several regularizations and with either None penalty or l2 penalty, and ''balanced'' or pre-calculated class_weight.'
    ):
        config = wandb.config
        
        log_reg = LogisticRegression(
            penalty=config.penalty,
            C = config.C,
            class_weight = config.class_weight
        )
        
        cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)


        scores = cross_val_score(log_reg,
                                 X_train,
                                 y_train,
                                 scoring='recall', # replace 'recall' with you favorite metric
                                 cv=cv)
        wandb.log({"Mean score":scores.mean()})


sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep_config, project="log-regr")
wandb.agent(sweep_id, function=train)
```

Answer (score -1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469762/weightsbiases-sweep-keras-k-fold-validation):

> We put together an example of how to accomplish k-fold cross
> validation:
>
> https://github.com/wandb/examples/tree/master/examples/wandb-sweeps/sweeps-cross-validation
>
> The solution requires some contortions for the wandb library to spawn
> multiple jobs on behalf of a launched sweep job.
>
> The basic idea is:
>
> The agent requests a new set of parameters from the cloud hosted
> parameter server. This is the run called sweep_run in the main
> function. Send information about what the folds should process over a
> multiprocessing queue to waiting processes Each spawned process logs
> to their own run, organized with group and job_type to enable
> auto-grouping in the UI When the process is finished, it sends the
> primary metric over a queue to the parent sweep run The sweep run
> reads metrics from the child runs and logs it to the sweep run so that
> the sweep can use that result to impact future parameter choices
> and/or hyperband early termination optimizations Example
> visualizations of the sweep and k-fold grouping can be seen here:
>
> Sweep:
> https://app.wandb.ai/jeffr/examples-sweeps-cross-validation/sweeps/vp0fsvku
> K-fold Grouping:
> https://app.wandb.ai/jeffr/examples-sweeps-cross-validation/groups/vp0fsvku

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand where stratified K fold will be used. I see some functions, but no example with a dataset.